# DST conflict on CET DateTime php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

I have problem (maybe bug) on `php`.

This is my code:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo 'UTC : '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('CET'));
echo 'CET : '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
```

And this is my query on mysql to get time with timezone.

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone as tz, now()
```

I expect to result must be same but this picture is result in same time:

[image]

I found problem is in [`DST(Daylight Saving time)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) on `CET` timezone.

Anyone have any idea to how can I fix it ?

- php version: 7.2
- server timezone : CET
- server OS : CENTOS

Comment: try with 'CEST '

Comment: @Mate dosn't work. You know actually I must fix it because I get this tz from db and run that code on php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not pass time zone abbreviations to `DateTimeZone`.  Use a fully qualified, locality-based [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) instead.  For example, `Europe/Berlin`.  It will properly discern CET from CEST depending on the date/time in question.

This is covered in the warnings at the top of [this page in the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).